# Why does this property assignment overwrite the prior property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = new Object();
var bar = new Object();
var map = new Object();

map[foo] = "foo";
map[bar] = "bar";

alert(map[foo]);  //This alerts bar, but what happens to foo?
```

This is one of those questions to help with your understanding of how `keys` are assigned in JS. Of course, I immediately tried the following:

```
for(var prop in map){

   console.log(prop + ' ' + map[prop]);

} //[object Object] bar undefined
```

And then simply:

```
map //This returns Object {[object Object]: "bar"}
```

What?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the answers but what happened to `foo`? Is there some kind of `delete` mechanism happening I never heard of?

Comment: Properties are strings. Every* object converted to string is `[object Object]`. If you want to have possibility to use a real object as a key you must use the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class of ES2015

Comment: There is no deletion happening there, you simply overwrite the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object bracket notation coerces the value its given to a string. Since your giving it an object, it calls the object's `toString` method and saves the key as `[object Object]`.

*Foo is overridden by bar because you are saving to the same key, `[object Object]`.*

Ie. your object looks like this:

```
{
  "[object Object]": "bar"
}
```

Comment: thank you! I guess my bewilderment moves to this: aren't foo and bar district objects, with their own names? I would think the interpreter, would understand that and therefore make two properties....

Answer (score 1):

When you use your objects `foo` and `bar` as property names, `.toString()` is implicitly run on them. So you end up with:

```
map['[object Object]'] = "foo";
map['[object Object]'] = "bar";

alert(map['[object Object]']);
```